# Method for streaming AAC+ audio in Python?

Tags: python, audio, aac+

I wish to play an AAC+ shoutcast stream in Python.  I have tried with bass_aac, an extension to the Bass audio library which claims to be able to handle AAC+ unsuccessfully.  I'm perfectly willing to write a binding to an external library if necessary.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using [GSTreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) via [gst-python](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) would be a good solution. GST can handle the whole audio pipeline from the HTTP streaming to speaker output.

I would suggest using `gst-launch` to get a feel of the API

```
gst-launch playbin2 uri=http://stream0.freshair.org.uk:3066/;
```

You can use `souphttpsrc` or other plugins to enable receiving metadata or more advanced output.

Note: The `;` in the shoutcast URL forces a audio only stream without any metadata. This is useful to localise issues relating to shoutcast/icecast and not the more general audio streaming,